# Identify developer-owned apps (App Scope ID)

Tags: android, android-studio

I read Android Developers' post
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/app-set-id#add-sdk

Does anyone explain to me how to use app scope ID and where we implement it?
I can't find any blog or tutorial about it.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence in the documenation you linked says:

> For use cases such as analytics or fraud prevention on a given device, you may need to correlate usage or actions across a set of apps owned by your organization.

Comment: It's different for each device, I wonder where we use the app set id?

Comment: @pro_hussain The way I read this is when you need to coorelate actions across multiple apps on the same device.

Comment: How can we correlate, have you any code or server examples?

Comment: @pro_hussain Nope. I am reading the same documentation you are. I would guess you have to find a way to compare ids. One possibility is to send the id to a server (via HTTP request or something). The first one to arrive is saved and later ones are compared with that first one.